# SEDE - database with id 256

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Let's use trivial query to list all databases:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases;
```

[Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482014).

Quick look at resultset, everything is ok. But highest `database_id` is 314 and message says: `313 rows returned in <1 ms`.

Let's write second simple query:

```
DECLARE @max INT = 10000;

WITH tally AS 
(
  SELECT rn = CAST([key] AS INT) 
  FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[1', REPLICATE(CAST(',1' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),@max-1),']'))
)
SELECT t.rn, d.*
FROM tally t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [min] = MIN(database_id)
                   ,[max] = MAX(database_id)
             FROM sys.databases) AS s
LEFT JOIN sys.databases d
  ON t.rn = d.database_id
WHERE t.rn BETWEEN s.[min] and s.[max]
  AND d.database_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t.rn;
```

[Live Demo 2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482013)

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════╦═════════════╦═════╗
║ rn  ║ name ║ database_id ║ ... ║
╠═════╬══════╬═════════════╬═════╣
║ 256 ║      ║             ║     ║
╚═════╩══════╩═════════════╩═════╝
```

It looks like there isn't any database with id 256.

One more query for quick check:

```
SELECT [255] = DB_NAME(255),
       [256] = DB_NAME(256),
       [257] = DB_NAME(257);
```

[Live Demo 3](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482020)

Output:

```
╔═══════════════╦═════╦═════════════════════════════════════╗
║      255      ║ 256 ║                 257                 ║
╠═══════════════╬═════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
║ StackOverflow ║     ║ StackExchange.Languagelearning.Meta ║
╚═══════════════╩═════╩═════════════════════════════════════╝
```

So all `database_id` are nice continuous range from 1-314 with gap. Is there any specific reason why there is no database with id 256?

Comment: Because 256 is an unlucky number to unicorns? ;)

Comment: Maybe there was a site there which was closed / deleted ?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  It could be the case :)

Comment: I don't see an explicit drop database [here](https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/f009ab6e0d6b85ae54f6) but if I have to guess I think the database for the Documentation beta is dropped after import, as I recall I did see that one earlier but is not present now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My earlier [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322251/sede-database-with-id-256#comment339831_322251) makes no sense.

If you look at the database_id's today you'll find that 141 is missing.

That is easily spotted if you order the sys.databases on create_date.

The first relevant user database (don't be bothered by the 4 systemdatabases and Data.StackExchange) is database_id 142 (StackExchange.Eosio.Meta) and the last one is database_id 140 (StackOverflow).

On Sunday at 03:00 UTC the [sp_Refresh_Database.sql](https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/f009ab6e0d6b85ae54f6#file-sp_refresh_database-sql-L129) stored procedure is run.

Under normal circumstances that script runs for each SEDE site database. It will create a [databasename]_temp database, fills the schema, create indexes, views and at the end, it drops the [databasename] and then renames [databasename]_temp to [databasename].

It turns out that SQL Server re-uses the database_id's. So it is NOT an autoincrement column, as explained by Rob on his blog [It depends](http://gumption.co.nz/2016/12/how-to-force-a-database-to-a-specific-database_id/).

With this knowledge I can now be pretty confident that database_id 141 belonged to the "old" StackOverflow database before the sp_Refresh_Database.sql ran. Because the last statements executed were

```
If Exists(Select * From sys.databases Where name = @DBName)
Begin
    Exec('Alter Database [' + @DBName +'] Set SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE');
    Exec('Drop Database [' + @DBName + ']'); -- this freed up 141
End

Exec('Alter Database [' + @TempDBName + '] Modify Name = [' + @DBName + ']'); -- this is 140
```

We can say for sure that next Sunday the first database that finishes its backup will get database_id 141 (as that is the current gap) but that is all the prediction we can do as the order is determined by (I expect) the duration of the backup completion of each database.

This all goes horribly wrong when a [batch doesn't run to completion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310186/the-sede-refresh-batch-failed-a-second-time-in-a-row) or less horrible when new databases are introduced as those don't require a drop database, in which case you could end-up with no gap at all.